# how to reset a number after it reaches a certain point in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am making a clock for my app with seconds and minutes. Every time the seconds get up to 60 I want to reset them and add a minute. I am not sure how I should do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make conditions like this..

```
if(second == 60)
{
    minute++;
    second = 0;
    if(minute == 60)
    {
        minute = 0;
        hour++;
    }
}
```